# Accomplishing Drag & Drop Items, Where the Values Change

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, user-experience

I have a question, may you take a look or watch this video? This video is explaining what I question about.

video: https://youtu.be/MVYmoz97wew

Again, how to accomplish that thing? I did research and found that's depend on some libraries such as Sortable / jQuery Sortable, how's the thing's going behind the screen when that items are moved, the values are change.

Maybe some articles how to accomplish that, point a direction. Need help

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should not ask questions like this. We all are here to help if you have got stuck somewhere while implementing your solution and not creating the whole solution for you on your behalf. Please try to implement it the way you have understood it and share your code where you find problems.

Comment: Start here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ Good Luck!